# Firebase UI auth sign in error api exception

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Just wondered if anyone is using firebase auth ui 4.2.0

When I start the auth process with a `startActivityForResult`

I get the error back...

> E/AuthUI: A sign-in error occurred.
>   com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Error when saving
>   credential.
>           at com.firebase.ui.auth.viewmodel.smartlock.SmartLockHandler$1.onComplete(SmartLockHandler.java:98)

Looks to be something to do with smartlock,

I've looked at some comments on git and this looked to be happening on a previous version but was supposedly fix in 4.2

Anyone else seeing this?

Answer (score 11):

1. Did you add your debug SHA1 fingerprint to Firebase Console?
2. By default, FirebaseUI uses Smart Lock for Passwords to store the user's credentials and automatically sign users into your app on subsequent attempts. Try setting it off by writing:

   ```
   startActivityForResult(
       AuthUI.getInstance()
           .createSignInIntentBuilder()
           .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
           .build(),
       RC_SIGN_IN);
   ```

You can read more about Smart Lock for Passwords on Android here : https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/

And you can read about different implementations of the Smart Lock with the FirebaseUI here :
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#smart-lock

Comment: Thanks for this, no such luck though.
I just want to check with regards to SHA1, we are talking about registering it to the project? url /settings/general/android:(project package) ?

I have added the debug at the above url

I've tried adding setIsSmartLockEnabled and I know get...
 Notifying auth state listeners....
Notified 0 auth state listeners


onActivityResult never fires.


Also worth checking, the only dependency for this is 

        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
        implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0'
?

Comment: For what I know you can't just check regardless to SHA1 with firebase-auth-UI. You do need to register it to a project on firebase. The SmartLock is basically a way that firebase saves the user name and password by device so users can just magically open the app without going through the login screen each time. If the SmatLock bother you and it's not essential for your app you should just disable it. I'm not a firebase expert, but implementing firebase is very easy I recommend you to do this short and easy course: https://www.udacity.com/course/firebase-in-a-weekend-by-google-android--ud0352